# bison says invalid option -- in a shell script

Tags: bison

I'm using flex and bison in Mac OS Maverick.  I can send the bison and flex command in bash without any problem.  But when I tried to issue the command using a shell script.  I got this error.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bison: invalid option -- 
Try `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bison --help' for more information.
flex: can't open minus.l
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'minus.tab.c'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'lex.yy.c'
: No such file or directoryut
```

The script is as follows:

```
bison minus.y -d
flex minus.l
gcc minus.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl -ly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From bison man page:

```
bison  [ -b file-prefix ] [ --file-prefix=file-prefix ] [ -d ] [ --defines=defines-file ] [ -g ] [ --graph=graph-file ]
   [ -k ] [ --token-table ] [ -l ] [ --no-lines ] [ -n ] [ --no-parser ] [ -o outfile ] [  --output-file=outfile  ]  [  -p
   prefix ] [ --name-prefix=prefix ] [ -t ] [ --debug ] [ -v ] [ --verbose ] [ -V ] [ --version ] [ -y ] [ --yacc ] [ -h ]
   [ --help ] [ --fixed-output-files ] file
```

Try `bison -d minus.y`. Same with gcc command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I suspected that it might be from the encoding. So I created a new script using vi. The file size of the new one is 4 bytes smaller. I hexdump and found that the original file is from Windows. The new script from vi works.